# 'While' loop does not stop even with the command if(*str == 'stop') and entering stop

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop

I want to write a function that replaces all occurrences of a character c with a character e. The functions seems to be working. However in the main, I want to be able to repeatedly enter a string, scan the character to be replaced, scan the character that will replace, and print the before and after, UNTIL the entered string is 'stop'. How do i do this? I have tried  defining 'stop' as a constant character string but that did not work. This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void replaceAll(char *str, char c, char e){
     for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++){
        if(str[i] == c){
        str[i] = e;
        }
     }
     return; 
}

int main(){
    char str[80], c, e;
    //repeatedly enter string;
    while(*str != '\n'){
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
        //jump out of loop
        if(*str == 'stop')
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &c);
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &e); 

        printf("replace all occurances of %c with %c in\n", c, e);
        printf("%s", str);
        //calls function
        replaceAll(str, c, e);
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated:)

Comment: c doesn't overload `==` for string comparison: `if(*str == 'stop')`. Use `strcmp` variant.

Comment: not to mention `'stop'` is also probably not what you want.  Note the use of single-quotes rather than double-quotes.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Not to mention that the compiler probably threw a warning about the single-quoted literal.  ;)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and google "c string comparison"

Comment: You need not look past the title of your question to find several glaring issues. In C, you do not compare string equality with `==` (you use `strcmp`) and `'stop'` is not a single-character (use double-quotes for *String Literals*)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the user to define *c* and *e* once before the loop starts.
Then move the following code to anywhere before the *while* loop starts. Best if you inform the user what to enter and not just use *scanf()*.

```
    printf(“please enter the char to find\n”);
    getchar();
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf(“please enter the char to replace\n”);
    getchar();

    scanf("%c", &e);
```

The main problem is with the following line:

```
// jump out of loop
if(*str == 'stop')
```

First, a single bracket is used for single characters and not for strings, where you should use brackets (“).

Second, use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)().

Third, to jump out of the loop, use *break;*.

```
// jump out of loop
if(strcmp (&str[0], “stop\n”) == 0)
{
      break;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, in fact when I added the  
    if(strcmp(str, "stop") == 0){
            break;
        } the  rest of the function stopped working, and it won't replace the characters.

Comment: Check now and also check the value of str

Comment: This finally worked!!                                                                                     
      if(strcmp (str, "stop\n") == 0){
            break;
        }